# Why Layout Gravity is not working in Android Studio?

Tags: android, layout

This is a easy problem I presume but I'm new to Android Studio so I don't really know what's wrong here.
When I use TextSize in editor it keeps shifting to top-left corner and I want to place it in center of the screen, I've used 
`android:gravity="center"`
 and also 
`android:layout_gravity="center"`. 
I've tried both of these in LinearLayout and RelativeLayout but it doesn't seem to work. I've also searched for solution here and the above solution seems to work for them but not me.

What could I do to solve this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` for display textview in center in `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It worked. I wanted that in center of screen so I also used ```centerVertical```. Is there any other way to do it. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: i did. it told me to wait for 5 minutes.

Comment: go to this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative for solution

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can try following code as well it also showing the same

Comment: yes, it is also working. Unfortunately I can accept only one answer. Thanks for your help.